# Static Socket client thread safety in multi-threded environment

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety

I have a program running on multi threaded environment . 
There i am creating multiple socket client to serve requests.
Since creating new socket always is costly thing , i have created a static socket client for all requests.
As below.

```
   Class SocketClient
{
    Static  Socket=null ;

SocketClient()
{
    sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
    sender.Connect(,,,,,,)
}

ServeRequest()
{
if(sender.Connected)
  {  
    Sender.send.......
  }   
}

}
```

I am creating a one instance and connect to server only for one time. Then if client socket connected i am using that connected socket with my all request is it ok. is it thread safe

Here how i am calling it from mutipl threads,

```
SocketClient client=new SocketClient();
 Client.ServeRequest()
```

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx): Instances of this class are thread safe.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti My question since i created static instance , there will be only once instance for all the request. Is it thread safe to use like that

Comment: Yes, according to MSDN it is. That sentence means that instance methods/properties can be accessed from multiple threads. Of course ITS code is thread-safe, it doesn't make YOUR code thread-safe (if you call multiple methods in sequence, for example). For example: if (socket.Connected) { ... oops someone else closed connection... }. Multiple threads may, for example, write on it concurrently. If you need more than that just put a lock around it.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Ok i got it. I forgot to mention one thing.I have edited my above example too. I am creating a instance and connect to server only one time. Then if client socket connected i am using that connected socket with my all request is it ok

Comment: Note also -- in addition to Adriano's comment pointing out that concurrent writes can corrupt the data being sent -- that presumably you expect some response from the remote host and you need to make sure you have a way of distinguishing response for one request from another. More to the point, while it can be done, it's unusual to have multiple threads sharing a single socket. While it can be made to work, it's possible you have a bigger design mistake here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho you are suggesting to create a new socket for each request. Isnt it too costly.

Comment: @user3597233: too costly for what? It all depends on your goals. More to the point, why do you have multiple threads each issuing apparently unrelated requests to the same remote host? How do you plan to distinguish between replies the remote host sends? These questions (which concern _correctness_ of the code) take precedence over the others (which concern only performance).

Comment: @PeterDuniho My understanding was when we are receiving data, it is coming in a sequence. Data will not mix , it will come as a single stream. we will get complete response at the client end at once. May be we have to call receive two times but it come as single continuous data stream.Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: One hopes that even if your code isn't thread-safe, the remote host's is and that it will be careful to send each individual response as contiguous bytes. But how will you guarantee that those responses are received in the same order in which your requests were sent? If you have multiple threads all sharing the same socket, is there something about the protocol that identifies the appropriate thread for a response? Note I'm not saying this _must_ be a problem; just that your scenario is unusual enough that it _might_ be a mistake.